# Can Android application make a call and send sms during the call?

Tags: android

I want to make a call from my android application. Once the call is connected, can my application send sms also during the call ? If yes, how can i make this work in PhoneGap ?

Thanks for the help.

Rajeev

Comment: where do you want to implement it?? android or phonegap??

Comment: In Phonegap for android platform......